# Help programmatically add text to an existing PDF

Tags: c++, pdf

I need to write a program that displays a PDF which a third-party supplies.  I need to insert text data in to the form before displaying it to the user.  I do have the option to convert the PDF in to another format, but it has to look exactly like the original PDF.  C++ is the preferred language of choice, but other languages can be investigated (e.g. C#).  It need to work on a Windows desktop machine.

What libraries, tools, strategies, or other programming languages do you suggest investigate to accomplish this task?  Are there any online examples you could direct me to.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: PERL has some libraries in CPAN that let you open PDF and modify them and it runs on Windows, but I doubt you want to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html):

> The PoDoFo library is a free, portable
>   C++ library which includes classes to
>   parse PDF files and modify their
>   contents into memory. The changes can
>   be written back to disk easily. The
>   parser can also be used to extract
>   information from a PDF file (for
>   example the parser could be used in a
>   PDF viewer). Besides parsing PoDoFo
>   includes also very simple classes to
>   create your own PDF files. All classes
>   are documented so it is easy to start
>   writing your own application using
>   PoDoFo.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp is a free library that you can use in .Net applications. Take a look at the [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) page - that is for the iText project, which is a Java library. iTextSharp is part of that project, and is a port to C# and .Net.

Answer (score -1):

Consider Python It have a lot PDF librarys (both creating and extracting) eg:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfsplit/0.4.2

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JagPDF/1.4.0

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/20091129

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/podofo/0.0.1

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFPDF/1.52

There are also good tools for using C/C++ code in Python and to create .exe form Python scripts. If you decide to use different language consider Python as prototyping language!